# Top of full html div cutting off

Tags: html, css

I have a div that I want to take up the full view height and it seems like the top is getting cut off.

Here is the html code:

```
<body>
    <div id="backdiv">
        <h1>Index</h1>
    </div id="backdiv">
<body>
```

and the css:

```
#backdiv {
    margin: 0px
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #648880, #293f50);
}
```

When I load it to chrome however it seems like it's not going all the way to the top, here's a picture:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can change it to go all the way to the top?

Comment: Your html is wrong bud, you don't need the id on the closing tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an `<h1>`  Try removing its `margin` with `margin: 0;`  Otherwise, you could force a new block formatting context by adding `#backdiv {overflow: auto;}`

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#backdiv {
    margin: 0px
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #648880, #293f50);
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="backdiv">
        <h1>Index</h1>
    </div>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you done this to remove all padding on `html` and `body`? Also, your `<h1>` needs no margin and your HTML is incorrect.

**CSS**

```
html, body, h1 {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div id="backdiv">
      <h1>Index</h1>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your code, try this:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="backdiv">
        <h1>Index</h1>
    </div>
<body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#backdiv h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

#backdiv {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #648880, #293f50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens when you don't set:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.